# sp.delete() does not work when object is non-integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to delete the final row of an array, the array is named 'A'. This  array happens to have some negative and float values in it.

```
#The final section of A and I'm trying to delete the last row
[[ 5.07000000e-03, -1.94058770e+03,  2.46074125e-01],
 [ 5.07300000e-03, -1.98654320e+03,  2.40137473e-01],
 [ 5.07600000e-03, -2.03249897e+03,  2.34062954e-01],
 [ 5.07900000e-03, -2.07845501e+03,  2.27850567e-01]]
```

I tried using sp.delete in this way

```
sp.delete(A[-1,:],A)
```

and this error showed up

```
__main__:4: DeprecationWarning: using a non-integer array as obj in delete will result in an error in the future
__main__:4: DeprecationWarning: in the future out of bounds indices will raise an error instead of being ignored by `numpy.delete`.
__main__:4: FutureWarning: in the future negative indices will not be ignored by `numpy.delete`.
```

Then I tried doing

```
sp.delete(A[len(A)-1,:],A)
```

and the following error showed up:

```
__main__:6: DeprecationWarning: using a non-integer array as obj in delete will result in an error in the future
__main__:6: DeprecationWarning: in the future out of bounds indices will raise an error instead of being ignored by `numpy.delete`.
__main__:6: FutureWarning: in the future negative indices will not be ignored by `numpy.delete`.
```

Is there anyway to fix this or is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: The parameters you have passed to `.delete()` make no sense at all.  Deleting the last row would be something like `A = np.delete(A, -1, 0)` - the parameters are the array, the index(es), and the axis.

Comment: `A1=A[:-1, :]` is all you need.

Comment: I see what's wrong now. Thanks!